# Time overlap in python string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings containing activities, start times, and end times.

`tasks = ['play, 0530, 0600', 'work,0730,0830', '...']`

How can I check if times overlap and print the overlapping duration and activities?
I've split the strings using

```
for act in tasks:
    act.split(",")
```

but not sure how to check if times overlap. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: split then convert to datetime object, then loop compare I think

Comment: Method to check overlap https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-any-two-intervals-overlap-among-a-given-set-of-intervals/

Comment: you should have each object contains {activity, start time, end time} and then you can do comparison between them, rather than in raw string.

Comment: might want to create a tracking variable outside the loop that keeps track of you last end time. that way you can check the next start time and compare it. if time is in 24hours and not 12 hours then you can just use convert the time strings into integers and compare. Also `act.split(",")` is a list, so store it in a variable in order to reference it later.